# contest form submission tracking users via GUID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, submission

The idea is not to use email addresses for uniquely identifying users for a contest submission form I need to build. Since emails are not unique and google allows emails with periods in them which makes it difficult to say if email is unique or not.

My requirement is the user is able to submit 2 ballots against an entry which gives them two spots. When the user lands on the page, I ask them if they are a new user or a returning user. If they are new user I generate a unique guid on server side and give it to them. If they are returning user I ask them to enter the guid provided and then I check this on my db to make sure its there and then show them the thank you page if they have casted all 3 votes or take them back to the page where they vote on facebook or twitter.

any thoughts? I think using guids I can guarantee noone would cheat the contest unlike emails which are not truly unique.

Comment: Do you really expect a _returning user_ to remember a `GUID` you gave them previously?

Comment: I could email it to them, email can still be a required field on the form?

Comment: Why not just have them logon with their email and a password if your that concerned that one user might use someone else's email address?

Comment: Well I'm trying not to identify user based on their email address also one can spam the contest using strategic aliases. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-based-on-email-address

Comment: Still don't understand why email/password is not suitable (its as secure and unique as you can get, and far easier for the user than typing in a GUID - I sure wouldn't use you site if this is what you make me do). And you can easily keep track of how many times a user logged in and/or submitted a form.

Comment: Email and password I can see being secure but the challenge here is we don't have a user registration/login screen designed and it will be hard to convince the team to do so. How about I emailed them a link with the guid and if they wish to return they simply click on the link ? Then I can check on the server side if the id exists and if they can cast more votes etc ?

Comment: I guess you could make that work - a bit like the standard 'forgot password' implementation where the user is emailed a token.

Comment: exactly, and it is also easy to implement.